# Monitoring keystrokes on macOS

Tags: macos, logging, keyboard

In Linux, one can use the program `xinput` to record or monitor keystrokes. This can be done by first identifying the id of the keyboard device via:

```
xinput -list
```

and then:

```
xinput -test $yourkeyboardid
```

outputs codes to *stdout* for each keypress.

Although running `xinput -list` in a terminal on *macOS* suggests the same approach is viable:

```
xinput -test $whateverid
```

the above fails to output codes to *stdout*.

How is it possible to report keystrokes from a keyboard on macOS if one wants to make a keylogger of sorts?  A preferred solution ideally incorporates `xinput`, or other similar command-line tool.

Comment: Not a command line but could help you - automator: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1700745?tstart=0

Comment: Do you ask about how to write a program or do you ask for a tool?

Comment: My goal is to envoke a script (which I write) that in any window/environment will report my keystrokes into a file until I press a given stop key, say space. If a tool exists (like xinput which works system wide in debian linux but only in xterm on mac) that is preferred. I am interested in a solution to that problem. Although xinput can be installed on a mac, it only works as expected in xterm, and running it in the background will not record keystrokes system wide. The solution by Jehy can work, but appears to require root privileges, which I find not optimal.

Answer (score 7):

Check [this](https://github.com/caseyscarborough/keylogger) keylogger sample on github. Seems not too old and rather popular.

Comment: This tool works as a solution, although only with root privileges. Bounty for you. Thanks.

Comment: No root privileges are required if you do log to a custom file, one in your home dir. Works well in 10.15.2. It doesn't distinct key up from key down, nor it handle key combinations.